# Autocomplete em input dinâmico

Tags: jquery, input, autocompletar, dinâmico

Bom dia pessoal.
Estou tentando implementar autocomplete no input dinamico mas não funciona. Já teste chamando class ou id e nada.

segue o código para que possam me dar uma luz mostrando onde estou errando.
Função Jquery que adiciono linha numa tabela dinamicamente. e a função autocomplete no campo descri (descricao do produto)

```
        $(document).ready(function(){

                //Atribui o evento click a classe .btn-insert-field
                $('.btn-insert-field').click(function(e){
                    //Remove ação padrão do link para não atualiza a página
                    e.preventDefault();

                    //Define o elemento onde será inserido os campos
                    var target  = $("#target");
                    //total de linhas criadas dinamicamente
                    //Será utilizado com indices pra serem removidos mais facilmente
                    var total = $("#target tr").length;
                    //Cria estrutura que será inserida
                    var html   = '<tr class="row-field-'+total+'">';
                            html   += '<td><input type="number" id="qtt" name="qtt[]" /></td>';
                            html   += '<td><input type="text" class="descri" id="descri" name="descri[]" style="text-transform:uppercase"  /></td>';
                            html   += '<td><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm  btn-delete-row" data-id="'+total+'">X</a></td>';
                        html   += '<tr>';

                    //Adiciona no final do elemento que foi selecionado anteriormente
                    target.append(html);
                });

                //Atribui a classe .btn-delete-row o evento click
                //É usado on porque o elemento será criado dinamicamente
                $(document).on('click', '.btn-delete-row', function(e){
                    //Remove ação padrão do link para não atualiza a página
                    e.preventDefault();
                    //pega o valor do data-id
                    var id  = $(this).data('id');
                    //Remove a linha
                    $('.row-field-'+id).detach();

                });

                $(document).on('DOMNodeInserted','.descri', function(){
                    $(this).autocomplete({
                        source:'pesquisa_produto.php'
                    });
                });



            });
```

Dentro do meu html eu mostro numa div ->

```
                                        <div class="off-3 col-6">
                                                    <table class="actions">
                                                        <thead>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <th>Quantidade</th>
                                                                <th>Descrição</th>
                                                                <th width="5"><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-insert-field">Adicionar</a></th>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </thead>
                                                        <tbody id="target"> <!-- aqui aparece a linha da tabela com 2 campos input criados automaticamentes -->

                                                        </tbody>
                                                    </table>
                                            </div>
```

Quando chamo a função autocomplete fora do input dinâmico funciona perfeitamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Troque `DOMNodeInserted` por `focus`. Quando o campo, seja criado dinamicamente ou não, receber o foco, irá ganhar o autocomplete:

```
$(document).on('focus','.descri', function(){
   // este if verifica se o campo já tem autocomplete
   if( !$(this).hasClass("ui-autocomplete-input") ){
      $(this).autocomplete({
         source:'pesquisa_produto.php'
      });
   }
});
```

Veja um exemplo:

```js
$(function(){
   var availableTags = [
   "ActionScript",
   "AppleScript",
   "Asp",
   "BASIC",
   "C",
   "C++",
   "Clojure",
   "COBOL",
   "ColdFusion",
   "Erlang",
   "Fortran",
   "Groovy",
   "Haskell",
   "Java",
   "JavaScript",
   "Lisp",
   "Perl",
   "PHP",
   "Python",
   "Ruby",
   "Scala",
   "Scheme"
   ];
   
   $(document).on('focus','.descri', function(){
      // este if verifica se o campo já tem autocomplete
      if( !$(this).hasClass("ui-autocomplete-input") ){
         $(this).autocomplete({
            source: availableTags
       });
      }
   });
   
   $("#addicionar").on("click", function(){
      
      $("#box").append('<input class="descri">');
      
   });
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="box">Digite "basic": <input class="descri"></div>
<button id="addicionar">Adicionar input</button>
```

Comment: Assim como sugerido também não funcionou. Estou utilizando a versão https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js  e 
 http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js  e https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js

Comment: Estranho. Adicionei um exemplo funcional na resposta. Veja que funciona normal.

Comment: Aqui comigo não funciona... porque será? E esta linkado corretamente.

Comment: Funciona em campos que não foram adicionados de forma dinâmica?

Comment: Estou testando aqui... parou de funcionar também! na função eu chamo a página pesquisa_produto.php que está assim:           <?php
include_once 'conexao.php';

$descri = filter_input(INPUT_GET,'term', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE descric LIKE '%".$descri."%' ORDER BY descric ASC LIMIT 5";
$pdo  = Conexao::getInstance();
$result = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$result ->execute();

while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
$data[] = $row['descric'];

}
echo json_encode($data);

?>

Comment: Tá vendo esse IF que coloquei: `if( !$(this).hasClass("ui-autocomplete-input") ){`? Faz um `else` nele e coloque: `console.log("já tem");`.  Aí vc vai clicando nos inputs mais de 1 vez e veja se aparece a mensagem no console. Se aparecer, o código está funcionando corretamente e o problema é no retorno do PHP.

Comment: Qdo eu depuro... olho no console nem entra no if... está dando erro na linha           $(document).on('focus','.descri', function(){

Comment: O que é mais estranho ainda. Vc usa outros eventos e não dá erro, só nesse que tá dando? Mt estranho.

Comment: Voltou a funcionar no input normal mas no input criado dinamicamente está dando erro quando chamo o $(this).autocomplete({ .....

Comment: Resolvido... criei um novo arquivo .php copiei os dados do antigo colei e voltou a funcionar... agora não me pergunte pq rs.. Vlw a força Sam.